# R delete non max values in redundant rows

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix that contains following:

```
   A   B   C   D  
a  1   3   2   5  
b  3   2   5   8 
a  2   1   0   9
a  4   2   1   3 
c  4   3   1   1
b  2   5   1   9
```

`A`, `B`, `C`, `D` are column names and 
`a`, `b`, `c`, `d` are row names.

I want to make it look like

```
   A   B   C   D  
a  4   3   2   9
b  3   5   5   9 
c  4   3   1   1
```

using R, Which is to 
1) order the row in alphabetical order,
2) and then if there are redundant rows (i.e. there are other rows with the same row name), pick a maximum value among the redundant rows for each column and delete the others.

I first used python to do this process, but I was wondering if there is 
more convenient way for this job in R.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a one liner using `data.table` you can keep the rows while converting to `data.table` and then apply `max` function over all columns using `lapply(.SD,...)` by the `rn` variable (the saved row names)

```
library(data.table)
data.table(m, keep.rownames = TRUE)[, lapply(.SD, max), by = rn]
#    rn A B C D
# 1:  a 4 3 2 9
# 2:  b 3 5 5 9
# 3:  c 4 3 1 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use data.table

```
dt_in <- data.table(matrix_in)
dt_in[, name := rownames(matrix_in)]
dt_max <- dt_in[, list(A = max(A), B = max(B), C = max(C), D = max(D)), by = "name"]
as.matrix(data.frame(dt_max))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `aggregate` function:

```
aggregate(matrix ~ rownames(matrix), matrix, max)
```